# Counting how many times each distinct element in a list occurs

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a list comprehension to calculate the frequency of each distinct value in a list, but I'm having trouble with the last part.

So far I have this:

```
frequency :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int,a)] 
frequency list = [(count y list,y) | y <- rmdups ]
```

Something is wrong with the last part involving `rmdups`.

The `count` function takes a character and then a list of characters and tells you how often that character occurs, the code is as follows:

```
count :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Int
count x [] = 0
count x (y:ys) | x==y = 1+(count x ys)
               | otherwise = count x ys
```

Comment: So, "something is wrong with the part last involving rmdups" but you don't tell us what is wrong, what (if any) error message or output you get, and you don't show the definition (or even just the type) of `rmdups`. How are we supposed to answer?

Comment: Sorry I wrote rmdups in there when I actually meant nub

Answer (score 24):

You could also use a associative array / finite map to store the associations from list elements to their count while you compute the frequencies:

```
import Data.Map (fromListWith, toList)

frequency :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
frequency xs = toList (fromListWith (+) [(x, 1) | x <- xs])
```

Example usage:

```
> frequency "hello world"
[(' ',1),('d',1),('e',1),('h',1),('l',3),('o',2),('r',1),('w',1)]
```

See documentation of [`fromListWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.0/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v%3afromListWith) and [`toList`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.0/docs/Data-Map-Lazy.html#v%3atoList).

Answer (score 15):

I had to use `Ord` in instead of `Eq` because of the use of `sort`

```
frequency :: Ord a => [a] -> [(Int,a)] 
frequency list = map (\l -> (length l, head l)) (group (sort list))
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a solution using `Control.Arrow`:

```
frequency :: Ord a => [a] -> [(Int,a)] 
frequency = map (length &&& head) . group . sort
```

This is the same function as [ThePetest's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10398874), except

```
λ f g l -> (f l, g l)
```

is replaced with

```
-- simplified type signature
(&&&) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> c) -> a -> (b, c)
```

from `Control.Arrow`. If you want to avoid the import,

```
liftA2 (,) :: Applicative f => f a -> f b -> f (a, b)
```

works as well (using the Applicative instance of `(->) r`).

Comment: In case somebody is looking for an off-the-shelf solution, there is a `count` method in [`Data.List.Unique`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Unique-0.4.7.2/docs/Data-List-Unique.html). The implementation is quite similar to the one given in this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming `rmdups` has the type

```
rmdups :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
```

Then you're missing a parameter for it.

```
frequency :: Eq a => [a] -> [(Int,a)] 
frequency list = [(count y list,y) | y <- rmdups list]
```

But the error you're getting would be helpful with diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

Your `rmdups` function is just `nub` from `Data.List`.

Answer (score -1):

Replacing `rmdups`  with `nub list` worked for me like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

Hahahaha there is an `rmdups` on pg. 86 of **Programming in Haskell** by Graham Hutton. It is perfect and recursive. It is also handy in a great many situations.

Here is my one line `rmdups` and it produces the same results as `nub`or Hutton's.

```
rmdups ls = [d|(z,d)<- zip [0..] ls,notElem d $ take z ls]
```

It can well be used to count distinct elements of a list.

```
dl = "minimum-maximum"
[ (d,sum [1|x<-dl,d == x]) | d<-rmdups dl]
```

[('m',6),('i',3),('n',1),('u',2),('-',1),('a',1),('x',1)]