# Implement a function to count frequency of each element in a list

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I try to write a program which will count the frequency of each element in a list.

```
    In: "aabbcabb"
    Out: [("a",3),("b",4),("c",1)]
```

You can view my code in the following link: http://codepad.org/nyIECIT2
In this code the output of unique function would be like this

```
     In: "aabbcabb"
     Out: "abc"
```

Using the output of unique we wil count the frequency of the target list.
You can see the code here also:

```
    frequencyOfElt xs=ans
       where ans=countElt(unique xs) xs
          unique []=[]
      unique xs=(head xs):(unique (filter((/=)(head xs))xs))
      countElt ref target=ans'
             where ans'=zip ref lengths
            lengths=map length $ zipWith($)(map[(=='a'),(==',b'),(==',c')](filter.(==))ref)(repeat target)

    Error:Syntax error in input (unexpected symbol "unique")
```

But in ghci 6.13 other type of error are showing also

Few asked me what is the purpose of using [(=='a'),(==',b'),(==',c')]. 
What I expect: If ref="abc" and target="aabbaacc"
then

```
    zipWith($) (map filter ref)(repeat target)
```

will show ["aaaa","bb","cc"] then I can use map length over this to get the frequency
Here for filtering list according with the ref i use [(=='a'),(==',b'),(==',c')]

I assume some logical error lies [(=='a'),(==',b'),(==',c')] here..

Comment: put the code and error in your question.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Bindings in the same `where` clause must start in the same column.

Comment: @Daniel: indentation is wrong here only. u can see my code here http://codepad.org/3WdfZKev. I know i will get help from u

Comment: no it's wrong there too. You can see the line number colored in red for you to notice it better. It says there "ERROR line 3 - Syntax error in input (unexpected symbol "unique")". To not make such error, make the keyword "where" the only word on a line.

Comment: @WillNess: Now see the code, pls: http://codepad.org/i1gfAH4t

Comment: @SaugataBose Repeat after me: "*All* bindings in the same where clause must start in the same column." Then compare the columns of `ans` and `unique`, which are in the same where clause.

Comment: @SaugataBose new error is also shown there. I copy: "ERROR line 7 - Improperly terminated character constant". Do not write such long lines. See here http://codepad.org/ZxhC7ZqW your code with shorter lines. You use there `',b'` but a character constant can hold only one character.

Comment: @SaugataBose Care to explain what you think this one: `map[(=='a'),(==',b'),(==',c')]` is supposed to mean?

Comment: @Ingo: Thnx for ur effort. I try to find the list. If it is equal to a then it will produce element conating a, if its containing b it will produce element containng b. for ur considertion I put some test case in my question.

Comment: I'm going through your code step by step, check it out: http://hpaste.org/78070 . I'm not finished yet. :)

Comment: i m grateful for ur kind effrt

Comment: thanks, @Daniel ... I've just made some false steps there and ended up just rewriting it with simple list comprehension. But the OP's idea was actually nice - zipping with application!... It probably should be re-written again with Applicative ZipList or something... :)

Comment: And my hope increases as 2 mentors are engaged here.thnx for ur involvment

Comment: @WillNess: Will, did you find error there?

Comment: Your code wasn't right as is. For one thing, you can't map lists over lists; you can only map functions over lists. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Haskell - Counting how many times each distinct element in a list occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398698/haskell-counting-how-many-times-each-distinct-element-in-a-list-occurs)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You didn't say whether you want to write it whole on your own, or whether it's OK to compose it from some standard functions.

```hs
import Data.List

g s = map (\x -> ([head x], length x)) . group . sort $ s

-- g = map (head &&& length) . group . sort     -- without the [...]
```

is the standard quick-n-dirty way to code it.

---

OK, so your original idea was to **Code it Point-Free Style** ([certain tune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gangnam_Style) playing in my head...):

```hs
frequencyOfElt :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [(a,Int)]
frequencyOfElt xs = countElt (unique xs) xs     -- change the result type
  where 
    unique [] = []
    unique (x:xs) = x : unique (filter (/= x) xs)  

    countElt ref target =   -- Code it Point-Free Style  (your original idea)
      zip 
        ref $               -- your original type would need (map (:[]) ref) here
        map length $
          zipWith ($)       -- ((filter . (==)) c) === (filter (== c))
            (zipWith ($) (repeat (filter . (==))) ref)  
            (repeat target)
```

I've changed the type here to the more reasonable `[a] -> [(a,Int)]` btw. Note, that

```hs
zipWith ($) fs (repeat z) === map ($ z) fs
zipWith ($) (repeat f) zs === map (f $) zs === map f zs
```

hence the code simplifies to

```hs
    countElt ref target =  
      zip 
        ref $              
        map length $
          map ($ target)      
            (zipWith ($) (repeat (filter . (==))) ref)
```

and then

```hs
    countElt ref target =  
      zip 
        ref $              
        map length $
          map ($ target) $
            map (filter . (==)) ref
```

but `map f $ map g xs === map (f.g) xs`, so

```hs
    countElt ref target =  
      zip 
        ref $              
        map (length . ($ target) . filter . (==)) ref      -- (1)
```

which is a bit clearer (for my taste) written with a list comprehension,

```hs
    countElt ref target =  
        [ (c, (length . ($ target) . filter . (==)) c) | c <- ref] 
     == [ (c,  length ( ($ target) ( filter (== c))))  | c <- ref]     
     == [ (c,  length $ filter (== c) target)          | c <- ref]
```

Which gives us an idea to re-write (1) further as

```hs
    countElt ref target =  
      zip <*> map (length . (`filter` target) . (==)) $ ref
```

but this obsession with point-free code becomes pointless here.

---

So going back to *the readable* list comprehensions, using a standard `nub` function which is equivalent to your `unique`, your idea becomes

```hs
import Data.List

frequencyOfElt xs = [ (c, length $ filter (== c) xs) | c <- nub xs]
```

This algorithm is actually quadratic (`~ n^2`), so it is worse than the first version above which is dominated by `sort` i.e. is linearithmic (`~ n log(n)`).

---

This code though can be manipulated further by a principle of equivalent transformations:

```hs
  = [ (c, length . filter (== c) $ sort xs) | c <- nub xs]
```

... because searching in a list is the same as searching in a list, sorted. Doing more work here -- will it pay off?..

```hs
  = [ (c, length . filter (== c) $ sort xs) | (c:_) <- group $ sort xs]
```

... right? But now, `group` had already grouped them by `(==)`, so there's no need for the `filter` call to repeat the work already done by `group`:

```hs
  = [ (c, length . get c . group $ sort xs) | (c:_) <- group $ sort xs]
            where get c gs = fromJust . find ((== c).head) $ gs

  = [ (c, length g) | g@(c:_) <- group $ sort xs]

  = [ (head g, length g) | g <- group (sort xs)]

  = (map (head &&& length) . group . sort) xs
```

isn't it? And here it is, the same linearithmic algorithm from the beginning of this post, actually *derived* from *your* code by factoring out its hidden common computations, making them available for reuse and code simplification.

Comment: Thanx. Thank u very much. But I want to keep Alive and try to klnw in which area i did ta mstake.thakkkk will

Comment: why `[head x]` instead of just `head x`? It is arbitrary to wrap the value in some construct without apparent reason. Hence confusing.

Comment: @Ingo that's what the example answer in the Q is showing. Perhaps that was an oversight on the OP part.

Comment: @WillNess I see. But then, your solution can count not only characters.

Comment: @Ingo but lists are homogeneous in Haskell, so all is good. :)

Comment: @WillNess Thanx for ur tremendous effort.Can i get the code in codapad link?

Comment: I will have that certain tune in my head all night now. >_<

Comment: @SaugataBose http://hpaste.org/78070 has most all the variants (including some false steps). Or copy from here; enter the editing history by clicking "edited X hours ago" below the post, and at the top revision, click ["source"](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/549609fc-aed1-4cdc-8d3b-4b425f6dcbe2/view-source).

Comment: Another point-free way: `g = map (head &&& length) . group . sort`

Answer (score 12):

Using [multiset-0.1](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/multiset/0.1/doc/html/Data-MultiSet.html#10):

```
import Data.Multiset

freq = toOccurList . fromList
```