# Haskell - Is there a standard function to provide a count of each item in a list?

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Counting unique elements in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710976/counting-unique-elements-in-a-list)
>   [Count frequency of each element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517114/count-frequency-of-each-element-in-a-list)

I tried Google, Hoogle, and here and didn't see anything obvious.

It should take `['a', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'e', 'a', 'e']` and return `[('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('e', 3)]` or something to that effect.

Answer (score 6):

I would use a Map for counting:

```
import qualified Data.Map as M

countElems :: (Ord a) => [a] -> M.Map a Int
countElems = M.fromListWith (+) . flip zip (repeat 1)
```

Comment: Every time this question is asked (and I see it all the time), there is this solution and the `group . sort` based solution.  I prefer this one for basically no good reason.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can use e.g.

```
import Data.List
import Control.Arrow

map (head &&& length) $ group $ sort ['a', 'b', 'e', 'c', 'e', 'a', 'e']
```

Or consider using a [MultiSet](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/multiset/0.2.1/doc/html/Data-MultiSet.html).

Comment: Yes, Control.Arrow. Thanks, luqui!