# How to count the occurences of every element in a list in Haskell fast?

Tags: haskell, optimization, functional-programming

I have  list of strings that represent classes of classified objects.

```
["Class 1", "Class 2", "Class 1", "Class 2", "Class 3"]
```

would yield `[2,2,1]` (their order does not matter).

I have tried two functions that do this, both of them are too slow for large lists (thousands of items).

This is the first one that does slighly better than the second one:

```
uniqueClassesCounts :: [String] -> [Int]
uniqueClassesCounts classNames=
  let uniqueClasses = nub classNames
  in [length (filter (== cls) classNames) | cls <- uniqueClasses]
```

And the slower one:

```
uniqueClassesCounts :: [String] -> [Int]
uniqueClassesCounts classNames= map length (group (sort (classNames)))
```

I am pretty sure there must be a way to do this in linear time (my brief researched showed that the above functions both work in quadratic time and worse).

How can I make this thing faster? It is the unexpected bottleneck of my code, more than 70% of time is spent on it.

Comment: See also (the answers to; the question itself is unclear) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398698/counting-how-many-times-each-distinct-element-in-a-list-occurs

Comment: Try iterating the list recursively while keeping count of the items with a parameter of type [`Map`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.4.0.0/docs/Data-Map.html). Update the `Map` with `insertWith' (+) className 1 map`.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions, I tried them and it seems my code has sped up by approximately 40%.

Comment: Neither of your attempts is quadratic.  While the documentation for `nub` claims it is O(n^2), this is false.  It is O(kn) for k the number of distinct classes and n the length of the list.  So, your `nub` attempt above is actually O(n), if the number of classes doesn't increase with increasing n.  The `sort` version is more or less O(n log n).  These are asymptotic results, so actual numbers matter.  If you try 100000 elements with 5 classes, `nub` will outperform `sort`.  If you try 100000 elements with 10000 classes, you'll find `sort` is an order of magnitude faster than `nub`.

Comment: A hashmap, like nub, is O(n), but performs better with large k.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr: it is not really "false" that it is *O(n^2)*, since *k* is at most *n*, and thus if *f* scales (strictly) greater than *g*, then *O(g)* implies *O(f)*. But you are correct that in (very) rare cases, a hashmap could also scales that much, but typically, if there are no hash collissions, it will scale a lot faster.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear -- when I said "a hashmap", I meant "a hashmap based solution to the problem".  With O(1) lookups, your hashmap solution is O(n) for the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably better to use a `HashMap` or some other collection that can make lookups efficient.

You could do this with [**`fromListWith :: (Eq k, Hashable k) => (v -> v -> v) -> [(k, v)] -> HashMap k v`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.20/docs/Data-HashMap-Strict.html#v:fromListWith):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

import Data.HashMap.Strict(fromListWith)

uniqueClassesCounts :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => [a] -> HashMap a Int
uniqueClassesCounts = fromListWith (+) . map (,1)
```

If you are only interested in the counts, we can use [**`elems :: HashMap k v -> [v]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.20/docs/Data-HashMap-Strict.html#v:elems):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

import Data.HashMap.Strict(elems, fromListWith)

uniqueClassesCounts :: (Eq a, Hashable a) => [a] -> [Int]
uniqueClassesCounts = elems . fromListWith (+) . map (,1)
```

Comment: Nice solution! It'd be interesting to hear from OP how much the `HashMap` improved performance.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, I will try to implement this tomorrow. I will be sure to update you @GoodNightNerdPride as well.